# Thumbnails in Ubuntu 19.10 in list mode

Tags: files, thumbnails

If I set the layout in files to grid mode, I get image thumbnails, but not when in list mode. I've checked ownership & permissions on `~/.cache/thumbnails` and also emptied the folder.

Am i missing something or is this the way its designed? Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thumbnails are shown in list mode, provided "zoom" is set to at least 150%.

Comment: Guess who feels stupid now.

Comment: "Discoverability" is not always top notch in Gnome Shell :-)